# GetElementById not working in JQuery autocomplete call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have this code which I have analysed in Firebug and it is really confusing me.  When I call this code the line `alert(selectedAmenities);` shows the correct data but this line

```
source: "/Results/GetAmenities?selected=" + selectedAmenities,
```

always shows `selectedAmenities` as being an empty string.  Why is this?

```
$(function () {

    var selectedAmenities = "";

    function amenitiesLog(message) {
        if (!$('#amenitiesLog div:contains(' + message + ')').length) {
            $("<div/>").text(message).appendTo("#amenitiesLog");
            $("<br/>").text("").appendTo("#amenitiesLog");
            $("#amenitiesLog").scrollTop(0);

            selectedAmenities = document.getElementById("amenitiesLog").innerHTML;
            alert(selectedAmenities);
        }
    }

    $("#Amenities").autocomplete({
        source: "/Results/GetAmenities?selected=" + selectedAmenities,
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item != null) amenitiesLog(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When you've already gotten the element four times, why would you suddenly need to use plain javascript to get the element, and why not just cache it from the getgo ?

Comment: *"When I call this code the line `alert(selectedAmenities);` shows the correct data"*... then `getElementById` works perfectly fine. The line `source: "/Results/GetAmenities?selected=" + selectedAmenities` is executed **before** you call  `amenitiesLog(ui.item.value);` and it is only executed **once**. At the moment you read `selectedAmenities`, it is an empty string and changing the value later does not update `"/Results/GetAmenities?selected=" + selectedAmenities`. If I have `var foo = '42'; var bar = 'answer' + foo; foo = '21';`, then `bar` stays `'answer42'`, it does not change with `foo`.

Comment: Thanks Felix - so what is the solution?

Comment: You can use a callback instead and make the Ajax call yourself. Have a look at the overview section in the docs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I call this code the line `alert(selectedAmenities);` shows the correct data

Then `getElementById` works perfectly fine.

---

### The problem

The line

```
source: "/Results/GetAmenities?selected=" + selectedAmenities
```

is executed **before** you call `amenitiesLog(ui.item.value);` and it is only executed **once**.
At the moment you read `selectedAmenities`, it is an empty string and changing the value later does not update `"/Results/GetAmenities?selected=" + selectedAmenities`.

If I have

```
var foo = '42'; 
var bar = 'answer' + foo; 
foo = '21';
```

then `bar` stays `'answer42'`, it does not change with `foo`. `bar` contains a string and has no relation to the variable `foo` whatsoever.

---

### The solution

Instead of using the URL as source, it seems you should use a callback. Have a look at the overview section in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). Something like:

```
$("#Amenities").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, callback) {
         var url = "/Results/GetAmenities?selected=" + selectedAmenities + '&term=' + request.term;
         $.getJSON(url, callback);
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item != null) amenitiesLog(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

The difference is that now whenever the autocomplete is triggered, the function you assigned to `source:` will be called and it  re-evaluates  `"/Results/GetAmenities?selected=" + selectedAmenities` every time.

Comment: In general it is a function you provide to some existing code and which is called by that code on your behalf. If you refer to the `callback` variable, it is the function where you have to pass the choices to. Have a look at the documentation, it is described there: *"The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments: [...] A response callback, which expects a single argument to contain the data to suggest to the user."*

Comment: I have to pass "term" as well in the query string

Comment: The search term is a property of the `request` object... updated the code.

Comment: i see now - nice - never would have got that on my own.

Comment: The documentation contains some examples which show different uses of `source` with a function... might be worth having a look at it.